# join() waiting forever when exception occurs, jvm shutdown hook not working

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, process, jvm, shutdown-hook

I am trying to shutdown the application, whenever any Fatal 
Error/Exception comes but before shut down the application my current
thread/task should complete, so I have written `mainThread.join()` 
inside `run()`, its working fine when there is no exception. But whenever my 
`doTask()` throwing exception that time `join()` waiting forever.

```
public class POC 
{
    public void doTask() throws Exception
    {
        throw new Exception("Fatal Error");
        //throw new Exception("Fatal Error"); By commenting working fine.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        POC ob = new POC();
        final Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {   
                try 
                {
                    System.out.println("Join() Start");
                    mainThread.join();
                    System.out.println("Join() End"); //Why this is not printing?
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }
        });

        try 
        {   
            System.out.println("Before doTask()");          
            ob.doTask(); //User Defined Run()
            System.out.println("After doTask()");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)                    // FATAL
        {
            System.err.println("Exception : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        } 
    }
}

OutPut    :    0
Before Run()
Exception : Fatal Error
Join() Start
```

Why `System.out.println("Join() End");` is not printing?

Comment: > Please let me know, Is there any solution to release the deadlock and shutdown the jvm forcefully.

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple deadlock.
When you throw an exception, exception handler call `System.exit(-1)`, which is blocking, see javadoc:

> Terminates the currently running Java virtual machine by initiating its shutdown sequence
>
> ...
>
> The virtual machine's shutdown sequence consists of two phases.  In the first phase all registered `#addShutdownHook` shutdown hooks, if any, are started in some unspecified order and allowed to run concurrently **until they finish**.

So main thread is waiting in `System#exit` call until all shutdown hook will be finished and your only shutdown hook blocks and waits until main thread will finish (which is waiting in `System#exit` ... GOTO 1).

Comment: > Please let me know, Is there any solution to release the deadlock and shutdown the jvm forcefully.

Comment: @IndrajeetKumarSharma don't join on the main thread in your shutdown hook: it leads to deadlock and makes no sense